# react and redux app deployment : does the server receives all states?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, scalability

Im trying to build a website with React and using django backend.

I would like to know if using a React application I will need a server running React with

`npm start app`

or

`yarn start app`

or if I need to use `npm build` and upload  the index.html with the corresponding js files and the folder structure on my server?

In both cases what happens to the "states" used in react and redux ? are they transmitted to the server running npm start for example? in the case of a build are they also transmitted to the server?

I would like to know that for scalability issues.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React and Redux are both client-side only. They only live in the browser unless you manually write code to send data back.

Usually you would `yarn build` and upload the result of that.